# mySQL : Populate a column with the result of a query

Tags: sql

I have a table ORDERS with a column named cache_total_price, spent by each client.

```
+----+-----------+------------+-----------+------------------+
| id | client_id | date       | reference | cache_total_price|
+----+-----------+------------+-----------+------------------+
|  1 |        20 | 2019-01-01 | 004214    |                0 |
|  2 |         3 | 2019-01-03 | 007120    |                0 |
|  3 |        11 | 2019-01-04 | 002957    |                0 |
|  4 |         6 | 2019-01-07 | 003425    |                0 |
```

I have another table ORDERS_REFS where there is the price total spent for each orders id

```
+-----+-------------+------------+----------+---------------+------------+
| id  | order_id    | name       | quantity | unit_price    | total_price|
+-----+-------------+------------+----------+---------------+------------+
|   1 |           1 | Produit 19 |        3 |         49.57 |     148.71 |
|   2 |           1 | Produit 92 |        4 |         81.24 |     324.96 |
|   3 |           1 | Produit 68 |        2 |         17.48 |      34.96 |
|   4 |           2 | Produit 53 |        4 |         83.69 |     334.76 |
|   5 |           2 | Produit 78 |        6 |          5.99 |      35.94 |
```

I want to had to column cache_total_price the result of my query :

```
select sum(total_price) from orders_refs group by order_id;
```

result :

```
+--------------------+
| sum(total_price)   |
+--------------------+
|  508.6299819946289 |
|   370.700008392334 |
|  132.3699951171875 |
| 2090.1800079345703 |
```

I've tried some queries with Insert into select or update set, but didn't worked :(

Comment: I have removed the conflicting dbms tags. Put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used.

Comment: how your result is related  to your data sample ??  the number you show in result how are calcolated ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to update all the orders at once, in MySQL a subquery like this should do the trick. You could always add a WHERE clause to do one at a time.

```
UPDATE ORDERS 
SET cache_total_price = (
    SELECT sum(total_price) from ORDERS_REF where order_id = ORDERS.id
)
```

Comment: Just something to bear in mind - it's going to run the SELECT subquery for every row in the ORDERS table; if you have lots of rows in ORDERS, and each has lots of items, this will be a heavy query to run.

Answer (score 0):

```
 update t
set t.cache_total_price=x.sum_total_price
from ORDERS as t
join
(
       select order_id,sum(total_price)as sum_total_price 
       from orders_refs group by order_id
)x on t.id=x.order_id
```

In SQL Server you can try this one.

Comment: I tried but I'm getting some sql syntax errors